# Inconsistent date parsing using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I'm really scratching my head on this one. I've been using `SimpleDateFormat`s with no troubles for a while, but now, using a SimpleDateFormat to parse dates is (only sometimes) just plain wrong.

Specifically:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse("2009-08-19 12:00:00");
System.out.print(date.toString());
```

prints the string `Wed Aug 19 00:00:00 EDT 2009`. What the heck? - it doesn't even parse into the wrong date all the time!

---

**Update:** That fixed it beautifully. Wouldn't you know it, that was misused in a few other places as well. Gotta love debugging other people's code :)

Comment: I wish people would stop calling things “bizarre” and “weird” whenever they make mistakes. :/

Comment: Sorry. I was debugging code that someone many many years my senior had written, and I expected to be able to trust.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you want to use the `HH` format, rather than 'hh' so that you are using hours between 00-23.  'hh' takes the format in 12 hour increments, and so it assumes it is in the AM.

So this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse("2009-08-19 12:00:00");
System.out.print(date.toString());
```

Should print out

Wed Aug 19 12:00:00 EDT 2009

Answer (score 3):

The hour should be specified as HH instead of hh. Check out the section on Date and Time patterns in http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

You're printing out the toString() representation of the date, rather than the format's representation. You may also want to check the hour representation. H and h mean something different. H is for the 24 hour clock (0-23), h is for the 12 hour clock (1-12), (there is also k and K for 1-24 and 0-11 based times respectively)

You need to do something like:

```
//in reality obtain the date from elsewhere, e.g. new Date()
Date date = sdf.parse("2009-08-19 12:00:00"); 

//this format uses 12 hours for time
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
//this format uses 24 hours for time
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

System.out.print(sdf.format(date));
System.out.print(sdf2.format(date));
```

Comment: I'll try that, but I don't think it's going to solve the problem. In my application, I'm not actually converting back to a string. I'm saving the Date to a database, and it's wrong there, too.

Comment: Are your format strings consistent?  Some DBMSs will automatically convert values if they can figure things out, some won't.  Are the problematic values in a column(s) with different formatting applied at the db level?  Or coming from a connection that's got different parameters set?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2009-08-19 12:00:00".replace( " " , "T" ) );
```

## java.time

Other Answers are correct but use legacy date-time classes. Those troublesome old classes have been supplanted by the java.time classes.

Your input string is close to standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. Tweak by replacing the SPACE in the middle with a `T`. Then it can be parsed without specifying a formatting pattern. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 by default when parsing/generating Strings.

```
String input = "2009-08-19 12:00:00".replace( " " , "T" );
```

The input data has no info about [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or time zone. So we parse as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input );
```

If by the context you know the intended offset, apply it. Perhaps it was intended for [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (an offset of zero), where we can use the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

Or perhaps you know it was intended for a particular time zone. A time zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.