# Parse A Java Date

Tags: java

How can I parse the following date in Java from its string representation to a java.util.Date?

2011-07-12T16:45:56

I tried the following:

```
private Date getDateTime(String aDateString) {
    Date result = new java.util.Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
    try
    {
        result = sf.parse(aDateString);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), "Unable to parse date: " + aDateString);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse this type of date format in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013681/parse-this-type-of-date-format-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using the right date format pattern. The year/month/day separators are clearly wrong, and you need a literal `'T'`. Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

For the record, this is an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) combined date and time format.

Comment: you have one small error on the pattern - It should be `HH` instead of `hh` since his example date time is in military time. Not nit-picking just pointing it out. :)

Comment: Many thanks for the correction - fixed. That's [not the first time I've made this mistake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313280/inconsistent-date-parsing-using-simpledateformat), either...

Comment: Haha - that's quite a coincidence :)

Answer (score 3):

Your date format pattern is incorrect. It should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` .

To parse a date like "2011-07-12T16:45:56" you need to use:-

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the pattern you are feeding your SimpleDateFormat against the string you are feeding in.

See any potential discrepancies? I see 3.